# Magento 2.4.4 - Module coupon return $object_or_class must be of type object|string, null given

Tags: magento2, php, coupon, object, stripe

I have updated the Magento 2.4.4 version and also the stripe payment module.

I noticed that when I try to save or create a coupon from the Magento backend it comes back this error related to the stripe payment module:

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\Coupon, method_exists(): Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be of type object|string, null given
```

I spent several hours trying to fix this problem but couldn't find any solution
How can I fix this?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with an outdated version of the StripeIntegration module using PHP 8.x .
Try to update your StripeIntegration module:

```bash
composer require stripe/stripe-payments:^3.3 --ignore-platform-reqs -W
```